# Switch symlink and directory

Tags: bash, files, symlink

I have a directory and a symlink to it:

```
mkdir dir
ln -s dir dir_symlink
```

I want to replace the symlink with the directory and the directory with the symlink. Is there a way to do that atomically (or very fast)? The directory is large.

`dir` should now be a symlink to the `dir_symlink` directory (which is no longer a symlink, and contains the former contents of `dir`).

Comment: On any modern filesystem, a renaming is fast as it does not depend on the content / size of the directory / file.

Comment: It isn't possible to do it atomically with user-level tools alone. (It's possible to do it “very fast” with three `mv` commands, of course.) It might be possible with a union mount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I had to do this very often,
I would write a little bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "select symlink"
read -e -r symlink
echo "select directory"
read -e -r dir

var=$(echo "$dir" | sed 's/\///g')

rm "$symlink"
mv "$dir" "$symlink"
ln -s "$symlink" "$var"
```

the `sed` command removes the `/` that gets added when you use auto-complete for the input.
**Note:** it would remove all of them, also if you selected a directory tree.

You could tell `sed` to only match the end of line like this:
`sed 's/\/*$//g'`

Comment: bash (and ksh and zsh) can remove a trailing slash (and only a trailing one) with `${dir%/}`

Comment: thanks for this one @dave_thompson_085, should I update my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If the directories are on same filesystem `mv` is only renaming the directory and doesn't involve any copying. Just remove the old symlink, rename the directory using `mv` and create a new symlink.

Comment: This is not atomic, but it's the best you can do.

Comment: Updated the answer. On same filesystem, `mv` should be atomic as far as I know.

Comment: There are two operations involved: mv + ln. They can't be both done atomically

Comment: Of course, I don't think I have claimed such.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that if this is on a macOS machine, the new APFS filesystem supports atomic swaps for just this type of scenario. Although the functionality doesn't seem to be built into a command such as mv, it is accessible with a little bit of Swift code (the C code is almost identical, but you can easily just paste this into the Swift REPL, which is easier):

```
import Foundation
renamex_np("/path/to/file/one", "/path/to/file/two", UInt32(RENAME_SWAP))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Linux 3.15 (and glibc 2.28) the `renameat2` system call with the `RENAME_EXCHANGE` option will atomically swap 2 objects, such a directory and a symbolic link. Whilst this does not enable an atomic switch, it does allow a sequence which keep the names `dir` and `dir_symlink` pointing to the directory.

1. Create a symlink `tmp` pointing to `tmp`.
2. Swap `tmp` and `dir`.
3. Replace `dir_symlink` with a symlink pointing to `tmp`.
4. Replace `dir` with a symlink pointing to `dir_symlink`.
5. Swap `tmp` and `dir_symlink`.
6. Delete `tmp`.

In C:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

  symlink("tmp", "tmp");

  renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "tmp", AT_FDCWD, "dir", RENAME_EXCHANGE);

  symlink("tmp", "tmp_link");
  rename("tmp_link", "dir_symlink");

  symlink("dir_symlink", "tmp_link");
  rename("tmp_link", "dir");

  renameat2(AT_FDCWD, "tmp", AT_FDCWD, "dir_symlink", RENAME_EXCHANGE);

  unlink("tmp");
}
```